# AzureDevOps .NET Artifact Custom Version Number

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget

I want to have my .NET artifacts published to ADO Artifacts feed to have a custom version number like 1.10.0.47295-main with "-main" added as a suffix to denote a pre-release version in ADO Artifacts.

Here is a snippet of of my build pipeline YAML:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'nuget push'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '<MY_FEED_HERE>'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
    versioningScheme: byBuildNumber
    majorVersion: '$(MajorVersion)'
    minorVersion: '$(MinorVersion)'
    patchVersion: '$(PatchVersion)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to this:

```
name: '$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchVersion).$(Build.BuildId)$(suffix)'

...
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "dotnet pack"
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: Build.BuildNumber
```